# What is the difference between view.isHidden vs view.isVisible?

Tags: ios, swift

Can both be used interchangeably or  one is preferred over the other in certain situations where one is better?

Comment: What is `view.isVisible`? There is no such thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are different and not interchangeable.
Like already mentioned in the comments `isVisible` is not even a part of `UIView`.
With `isHidden` you can hide a view, it has a getter and setter.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622585-ishidden

`isVisible` is a property of some classes like `NSWindow`. It's read only and tells you if the instance is visible on the screen.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nswindow/1419132-isvisible